# Who says the Mourner's Kaddish for a synagogue member who had no family?

Tags: halacha, minhag, death, kaddish

If a synagogue member dies with no living family members remaining, who says the Mourner's Kaddish for them?  Can anyone volunteer to say Kaddish for them?

Comment: Why do you assume someone does? Maybe no one does. Does anyone sit Shiva?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an Ohr Same'ach ask the Rabbi article http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/10/Q1/

Ideally the closest relative should say it. If there are none, a close friend, or in the case of a noted rav, one of his students. Technically, anyone can volunteer to say it.

In many synagogues I have attended, the rabbi is always saying Kaddish for someone who either has no family members and / or has family members but they are not religious, elderly, or for some other reason do not come to a daily minyan.

I am also aware of some organizations that pay people to say kaddish for others.

Comment: I would add that in many synagogues the shammess gets paid to say kaddish for people as a way of supplementing his income.